# Can a Change Event Trigger include the same record multiple times?

Tags: trigger, asynchronous, platform-event, change-data-capture

I'm starting to play with Change Event Triggers, building a handler framework and I'm not sure if I need to handle a scenario where the same record would be included in the same Change Event trigger context.

That is, one of the following scenarios:

1. A record is updated multiple times within a transaction - would this ever cause multiple Change Events with "UPDATE" headers for that record?
2. A record has multiple types of DML executed on it within a transaction (such as inserted, then updated or updated then deleted)

I have tried many combinations of the above and have yet to produce a single Change Event Trigger context where the same recordId is present multiple times. I've thus concluded that it is not possible, but am wondering if anyone can confirm and if the confirmation is based on a more technical understanding of how these events are published as opposed to trial & error.